# Erro na linha de Codigo ao Salvar PDF

Tags: vba

Nesse código preciso salvar em uma pasta especifica que ao digitar a data do relatório ela direciona para local de salvamento porem no código

```
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=LocalNome, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=Abrir
```

Da erro e não sei como fazer para mudar